# play sound in PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, audio, adobe-reader

I'm using [Scribus](http://www.scribus.net/canvas/Scribus) (open source alternative to Adobe inDesign) to create PDF e-book and I'd like to add some show wav files to some pages. There is a possibility to add a javascript to make your PDFs interactive, but I simply can't add the sound. I tried hundreds of javascripts and none of them worked. Does anybody have an experience with adding sound to PDF or with Scribus?

I'm using Adobe reader to open PDFs and I have enabled javascripts. Other functions as pop-up alert does work but the sound simply doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

PDFs are not intended to be interactive as the standard was intended as a portable print format. That being said, you can attach files easily enough (pdftk is useful for this) but auto-running scripts in a PDF are a pretty major 'No-No' ever since the 'outlook.PDFworm'.
Just add in in the files to the doc and instruct your readers to click the link.

Comment: Sure I don't want to do auto-running script. As you said, I just want to make readers click some button (or text) to play a sound. How is this possible to create? I can't find any option in Scribus, could you recomand any other software where this can be done?

Comment: I'm sorry does pdfkt do it?

Comment: http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/

though I recall acrobat itself is able to attach a file

Comment: PDFs support multimedia annotations.

Comment: That's what PDF is mostly used for in practice, but the standard actually goes far beyond print documents. There's support for JavaScript, slideshows, embedded 3D objects, videos and whatnot...

Comment: @omz and gn1, Thanks guys but all this I already know, the problem is how to get them to my document, I just can't figure out the right javascript for a sound.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this just this week with my own tools.  The right way to do it is to create a SoundAction and trigger that however you like.  You shouldn't need to use javascript, just use whichever event you feel makes sense (PageView, etc) and hook up an Action which is a SoundAction.  Most basic WAV formats are supported, but you may need to do some conversion.

Comment: How can I create a SoundAction? Don't really get what you're saying. Do you use Scribus? Or could you post some link to a tutorial about this "events"?

Comment: I don't use Scribus, but poking around the site I saw a dialog for creating actions associated with particular events.  Maybe they don't have SoundActions...